# displaying images at top center of the screen

Tags: android

I wanted to display image at the top center of the screen in andriod [image],please let me know how to achieve this do i need to do any customization ?

```
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

you can do it if your parent layout is RelativeLayout like

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"      
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"     
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
  android:src="@drawable/piopular"
   android:id="@+id/userDp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and

```
In LinearLayout, use: android:layout_gravity="center".
```

Answer (score 0):

add these attributes

`android:layout_width="match_parent"`      this will make the image width the size of the screen
`android:layout_height="wrap_content"`     and the height scaled sized of the image's height
`android:layout_alignParentTop="true"`     now this attribute only works in relative layout

make sure the image view is in a relative layout tag